# MySQL Join two table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am making a query that is using user and reference table.

user table looks like this

```
user_id | user_name
1       | john
2       | smith
3       | sunny
```

and reference looks like this where reference_id is foreign key of user.user_id

```
id | user_id | reference_id
1  | 2       | 1
2  | 3       | 1
```

I can join these table and get below result

```
id | user_name | reference_id
1  | smith     | 1
```

but what i want to do is instead of reference_id i want to select user_name of referenced user like this

```
quote_id | user_name | user_name(reference)
1        | smith     | john
```

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to join the user table in twice, then

```
 SELECT * FROM 
   reference r 
   INNER JOIN
   user u1 
   ON
     r.user_id = u1.user_id

   INNER JOIN
   user u2
   ON
     r.reference_id = u2.user_id
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9469e/12/0